# Not able to assign generated value using IdClass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a customer entity whose primary is a composite key. In the composite key one of the field is auto generated value.

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Setter
@Getter
@IdClass(CustomerId.class)
public class Customer {
 
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
  private Long accountId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;


  @Size(max = 255)
  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CustomerId implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8048935613697415032L;
  private Long accountId;

  private Long id;
}
```

When i use below snippet of code to save the customer, i get below error

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Customer sc,
                             @RequestParam long account_id) {
  Customer saved = customerRepository.saveAndFlush(sc);
  return ResponseEntity.ok(saved);
}
```

**Error**
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR] value by reflection : [class com.demo.service.entity.core.CustomerId.id] setter of com.demo.service.entity.core.CusotmerId.id;

Comment: On your last line (`com.demo.service.entity.core.CusotmerId.id`) the is a tryping error in `CusotmerId`. Can that be relevant?

Comment: its a typo in copy.  Its CustomerId only.